# Can I use freemember to display member profile in normal site template

Tags: freemember

Can I use freemember to display member profile in normal site template? I just want to display the current logged in users details, shipping address etc, and on another page have them be able to edit.

How do I do this?

/// In response to Adrian/// UPDATE
I tried that but its not parsing anything through the member fields (the email etc are ok) but they are global variables. what is not parsing is the custom fields. I have tried putting the billing address directly into the memebrs profile from the backend, but it is still not showing up on the members details page.

```
{exp:freemember:members member_id="CURRENT_USER"}

      <h5 class="title">My Account</h5>
      Name: <strong>{screen_name}</strong><br>
      Email: <a href="mailto:#">{email}</a><br>
      Member since: {join_date format="%d %M %Y"}
      <div>


      <p>{username}: {email}</p>
        {billing_address}
                    {billing_address_1}
   {billing_address_2}
      {/exp:freemember:members}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Also this is my update form which I can seem to get working either-

```
**{exp:freemember:update_profile return="/decorate/myaccount" form_id="update_profile" form_name="update_profile"}

<p>
    <label for="email">Email</label><br />
    {field:email}<br />
    {error:email}
</p>

<p>
    <label for="screen_name">Screen Name</label><br />
    {field:screen_name}<br />
    {error:screen_name}
</p>
<div class="control-group"> 
    <label class="control-label">Billing Address</label>
    <div class="controls">
        <input type="text" name="billing_address" value="{billing_address}" class="span11" />
        <span class="help-block">{error:billing_address}</span>
    </div>
</div>


<p>
    <label for="current_password">Current Password</label><br />
    {field:current_password}<br />
    {error:current_password}
</p>

<p>
    <input type="submit" value="Update Profile" />
    <a href="{path='account/register'}">Create Account</a>
</p>
{/exp:freemember:update_profile}**
```

It will update the uesrname and email, but not this billing address.

Comment: You can post additional info by clicking the edit link immediately beneath your question. I accidentally approved your edit to Adrian's post (well it is Monday morning), but you should actually only edit answers to improve them in some way. Edits to your own question won't require approval either, so they'll show up immediately.

Comment: I'm still having this issue. Any luck? Only my username and email will update.

Comment: Hi I am having the same issue. but one thing i have discoverd if i am not passing CURRENT_USER in member id parameter, then its outputting all the available custom fields. {exp:freemember:members member_id="CURRENT_USER"} {first_name} {last_name}
{/exp:freemember:members} Could anyone give some solution for this? Thanks,
sus

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're looking for the FreeMember [members tag](https://github.com/expressodev/freemember/blob/master/docs/members_tag.md).

You can display the current user's profile like this:

```
{exp:freemember:members member_id="CURRENT_USER"}
    <!-- member fields -->
{/exp:freemember:members}
```

Then to update the current member's profile, use the [update profile tag](https://github.com/expressodev/freemember/blob/master/docs/update_profile_tag.md):

```
{exp:freemember:update_profile}
    <!-- member fields -->
{/exp:freemember:update_profile}
```